# Updating last_viewed field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a field that stores the last_viewed time. Is the best way to update this field by doing:

```
@course_enrollment.last_viewed = Time.now
@course_enrollment.save()
```

This field is a datetime as the database type and a timestamp as the rails migration type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling this in a controller I would probably do something like this:

```
class CourseEnrollment < AR::Base
  # ...

  def mark_as_viewed
    update_attributes(:last_viewed => Time.now)
  end
end

# in controller
@course_enrollment.mark_as_viewed
```

That way you can easily unit test it and remove a little logic from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

It is litte less code to do it like this:

```
@course_enrollment.update_attributes(:last_viewed => Time.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to [`touch`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch) the record:

```
@course_enrollment.touch(:last_viewed)
```

This would update the `last_viewed` and `updated_at` columns to the current time.